# memcmp return value, inconsistent comportment

Tags: c, libc, memcmp

Here is a small C code to highlight an issue on memcmp return value:

```
    char *str1 = "\200";
    char *str2 = "\0";

    int val1 = memcmp(str1, str2, 2);
    int val2 = memcmp("\200", "\0", 2);

    printf("val 1 : %d \n",val1);
    printf("val 0 : %d \n",val2);
```

Stdout is:

```
val 1 : 128
val 2 : -1
```

Is there an explication for the difference between the 2 functions call?
Thanks for your help.

the clang version:

Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0

Comment: By the way, using strncmp instead of memcmp gives the expected answer: 128 in both cases.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please add your toolchain versions and compilation options.

Comment: Not able to reproduce issue on `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4`

Comment: Not able to reproduce on Visual Studio either, I get `1` in both cases. onlinegdb: `128` in both cases https://onlinegdb.com/By7hhVaRQ

Comment: a couple thoughts: did you `#include <string.h>` for the correct prototype for `strcmp()`? Is the result different (consistent) with `signed char` or `unsigned char`?

Comment: Thanks every body.

I work with a macOS Sierra , so my kernel is a XNU 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

According to POSIX documentation, [`memcmp()` internally uses `unsigned char`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcmp.html).

I suppose your `char` is `signed`.

My guess (if I interpret https://godbolt.org/z/iOIbil correctly) is that `memcmp()` **with the literals does not invoke the code in the standard library** and the compiler itself replaces the call comparing `-1` and `0` (`'\200'` is `1 + 0b1111111`); the `memcmp()` call **with the variables invokes the code in the standard library** which converts the originally signed char to `unsigned char` and compares `128` and `0`.

Comment: It can be this. GG
the function memcmp seems to be call only one time. 
GCC should resolve memcmp("\200", "\0", 2) at the compilation. So the function call may be different.

Comment: An octal escape sequence shall be a number that can be representable as `unsigned char`, so the signedness of `char` shouldn't matter.